# Getting an instance member of an object in spring config

Tags: java, spring

I would like to get references to `a` and `b` using a Spring XML configuration file.

```
A a = new A();    
B b = a.getB();
```

Getting `a` is easy. It's just a bean declaration.

```
<bean id="a" class="A" >
```

How can I get `b`?

Comment: Why doesn't `a.getB()` work? Did you declare b as part of a's bean either through a constructor-arg or property?

Comment: I didn't declare `A` or `B`. They are part of a library that I am using. I guess `A` constructs `B` during its construction stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<bean id="b" factory-bean="a" factory-method="getB"/>` would do.

More info on spring factory bean/method is at http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-factory-bean.html

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out a few minutes ago but I appreciate your help anyway.